# Why can't I target li element with jQuery.click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html:

```
<ul id="ul_places_list"> 
  <li data-placesCode="6">  
    <a class="places_dtl" href="#">  
      <div>  
        <img src="http://dev.mysite.it/images/9_1418893365.jpg">  
      </div>  
      <label>Coming Out</label>  
    </a>   
  </li>
  <li data-placesCode="8">  
    <a class="places_dtl" href="#">  
      <div>  
        <img src="http://dev.mysite.it/images/9_1418893594.jpg">  
      </div>  
      <label>Friends</label>  
    </a>   
  </li>
</ul>
```

and this javascript

```
$(document).delegate('a','click',function(){//used to switch page
    console.log('delegate executed');
    var a = $(this);
    if(a.attr('href') != '#'){
        event.preventDefault();
        toPage(a.attr('href'));
    }
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ul_places_list li').click(function(){
        var code = $(this).attr('data-placesCode');
        console.log('code is: ' +code);
    });
});
```

The problem is that when I click on list element only the delegated click on the  element fires and not the event on the "li" element.
The "li" elements are added after an Ajax call.
What's going? What am I missing?

Comment: Your last `)};` should be `})`

Comment: @Neal - because he's closing the document ready statement incorrectly.

Comment: No no, I am really sorry, I did a typo here on SO. My code is correct, regarding parentheses.

Comment: Provide a jsfiddle demonstrating your issue.

Comment: @Ferex Then please see my answer re: `.on`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below answer actually is just a different implementation of your code.

The real answer is

> This `)};` was the problem. Should be this `});`.

From the other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27571915/561731

But you really should be using `.on` in new code :-)

---

#### Old answer:

Try using `.on`

So you can do:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function () {
    //event for anchor tag
});

$(function () {
    $('#ul_places_list').on('click', 'li', function () {
        //stuff for li click event
   });
});
```

Comment: Ok @Neal, the solution was using .on (besides correcting the typo). Could you tell me why?

Comment: @Ferexyour event delegation was all off. In your original code it assumed that the li was there on document ready, so if some event call created a new li, then the event would not get attached to it. Using on delegates that ANY li, past or in the future will get delegated with that click event.

Comment: Has event delegation some drawback, maybe on performance? Why can't I use event delegation if it fits every situation?

Comment: @Ferex using `.on` is how you should be doing event delegation. `.delegate` and `.click` are deprecated to my knowledge.

Comment: I did a few tests. If I put `$('#ul_places_list').on('click','li',function(){});` inside $(document).ready() it works. Outside it I have to use your instantly invoked function `$(function(){$('#ul_places_list').on('click','li',function(){});});` I don't understand why, because the #ul_places_list is not injected through Ajax

Comment: `$(function () {})` is just a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function () {})`

Answer (score 2):

This `)};` was the problem. Should be this `});`.

```js
    $(document).delegate('a','click',function(){//used to switch page
     console.log('delegate executed');
     var a = $(this);
     if(a.attr('href') != '#'){
      event.preventDefault();
      toPage(a.attr('href'));
     }
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#ul_places_list li').click(function(){
      var code = $(this).attr('data-placesCode');
      console.log('code is: ' +code);
     });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul_places_list"> 
      <li data-placesCode="6">  
        <a class="places_dtl" href="#">  
          <div>  
            <img src="http://dev.mysite.it/images/9_1418893365.jpg">  
          </div>  
          <label>Coming Out</label>  
        </a>   
      </li>
      <li data-placesCode="8">  
        <a class="places_dtl" href="#">  
          <div>  
            <img src="http://dev.mysite.it/images/9_1418893594.jpg">  
          </div>  
          <label>Friends</label>  
        </a>   
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You should vote to close the question as off-topic due to a typo then.

Answer (score 0):

if you add the "li" elements in a AJAX call you should add the click event after the elements load. Add this when ajax call end:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(addEventToControls)

function addEventToControls()
{
 $('#ul_places_list li').click(function(){
            var code = $(this).attr('data-placesCode');
            console.log('code is: ' +code);
        });
}
```

The add_endRequest Manager fire the handler when a Ajax Call end.

Comment: Never saw Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager, what is this?